# Weighted Singular Value Decomposition

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

Lemma: $\forall A\in R^{n\times n}$ and a  diagonal matrix $\forall W\in R^{n\times n}$ with $ w_{11}\geq w_{22}\geq ...\geq w_{_{nn}} >0$.  The singular value decomposition of A denoted by: $A=XM Y^{T}$, we have:

$tr\left ( WU^{T}AV\right )\leq tr\left ( WX^TAY\right )$

where $U^{T}U=I; V^{T}V=I;$; I is identity matrix.  When U=X and V=Y, the $tr\left ( WU^{T}AV\right )$ reaches maximum.

Please help me to prove the above lemma. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your Lemma is wrong. Consider the following counter example:

$W = \begin{bmatrix} 10 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 10 \end{bmatrix}$, $U = V=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $ X = Y = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ leads to

- $tr\left ( WU^{T}AV\right )= 101$
- $tr\left ( WX^TAY\right )  = 20$

which is a contradiction to $tr\left ( WU^{T}AV\right )\leq tr\left ( WX^TAY\right )$.

Comment: In your example, if $A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
 0& 10
\end{bmatrix}$ then $X=Y=\begin{bmatrix}. 
0 &1 \\ 
 1& 0
\end{bmatrix}$, and then the inequality is still true.

Comment: You are right but then your Lemma is trivial since $X=Y=U=V$ and it is no surprise that $tr\left ( WU^{T}AV\right )\leq tr\left ( WX^TAY\right )$.

Comment: Please oversee the lemma, remember that X, Y are calculated from singular value decomposition. U,V are only required to be unitary matrices.

Comment: I see. You want to proof that $tr\left ( WX^TAY\right )$ achieves the maximum value. The problem is that the singular value decomposition is not unique and different decompostions lead to different values.

Comment: I agree with you that in some cases, the singular value decomposition is not unique. However,  in this document [duke] (http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps111/spring07/notes/12.pdf), the author s state that the singular value decomposition is almost unique. for this assumption, I wonder the provable solution for the above lemma.